# Fixed Width EBCDIC Files in R

Tags: r, ebcdic

I'm trying to read some mainframe data encoded as EBCDIC into R, and am at a loss.  I'd like to avoid using an external program to convert the files, since I'm operating in a corporate environment.

You can find the example files [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByvX1v-WqaaASTdwV2ZYS0pBV00&authuser=0), with both ASCII and EBCDIC versions.  Note that there are no linebreaks in the EBCDIC versions of the file -- instead, I'd be specifying the width of each line manually.  R has the IBM500 encoding available in my environment, which should be the correct one for these files.

However, when I run the following commands, R seems to fail entirely.

```
layout <- read.fwf("EBCDIC_LAYOUT", widths = c(80), fileEncoding='ibm500')
data   <- read.fwf("EBCDIC_ZIPCODE", widths = c(32), fileEncoding='ibm500')
```

Where might I go from here?

Related -- some of the files I expect to use will be fairly large (1 GB or so).  Preferably, I'd like a solution that scales reasonably well.  (I tried packages like LaF, but they don't have the option to select encoding.)

Thank you very much!

Comment: What does "R seems to fail entirely" mean exactly?

Comment: It loads a single record with a series of garbage characters.